# How to redirect all /client pages to a different url?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

i want to modify my `.htaccess` file such that all sites with /client path redirect to another website without changing the URL. For example:

```
www.example.com/client/james
```

will show:

```
www.site2.com/james
```

Comment: "without changing the url" - although, strictly speaking, the URL _does_ change in your example? "all sites" - you have multiple domains? Is `site2` on a different vHost/server? Do you have other directives (this could influence how you would do this)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `site2` resides on a different vHost/server then you could do the following using a *mod_alias* `RedirectMatch`:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/client/([a-z]+)$ https://site2/$1
```

This assumes "usernames" are restricted to lowercase a-z letters, as in your example. But it still allows usernames of just 1 character.

However, if you have existing mod_rewrite directives then you should probably use mod_rewrite instead in order to avoid conflicts. The order of these directives is important.

For example, using mod_rewrite instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?client/([a-z]+)$ https://site2/$1 [R=302,L]
```